# Python: Only need specific values from dictionary; normalizing node-key pairs

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

So right now I have a dictionary `dataDict` that has keys with the value `'node-key'` where node is a specific csv fileheader and key is a field that may or may not exist in each file.  I have a `normalDict['Time']` that takes all the times from `dataDict[node-'Time']` and puts them in order.  I want to make a normalized dictionary for each `'node-key'` entry in `dataDict`.  So I iterate through the values of `normalDict['Time']` and if `i` is in   `dataDict[nodeTime]`, I want to add the value of `dataDict[nodeKey]` at the same position as `dataDict[nodeTime]` to `normalDict[nodeKey]`, and if value of `normalDict['Time']` isn't in `dataDict[nodeTime]`, I want to append a `'nan'` to `normalDict[nodeKey]`.

(my script currently graphs dataDict[nodeKey] vs dataDict[nodeTime] and I want to normalize the Time to include all node's times in one axis and adding 'nan's in dataDict[nodeKey] to where the values don't have an occurrence)

Edit: Clarification:
So lets say I have

So say that

```
dataDict['1-Time'] = ['12:00','1:00','2:00']
dataDict['2-Time'] = ['12:30','1:30','2:30','3:30']
```

I also have values for keys that have the same number of items as the two times listed so:

```
dataDict['1-lattitude']=['0','1','2']
dataDict['2-lattitude']= ['1','2','3','3']
```

And

```
normalDict['Time'] = ['12:00','12:30','1:00','1:30','2:00','2:30','3:30']
```

I would then like to have

```
normalDict['1-lattitude'] = [ '0', 'nan', '1', 'nan', 2', 'nan', 'nan']`
```

and

```
normalDict['2-lattitude'] = ['nan', '1', 'nan', '2', 'nan', '3', '3']
```

So that each key in the normalDict has equal amount of values as that in the `normalDict['Time']`

Here is my method and I have commented the specific line that makes sense in my head as to how to access the individual items for a specific key, but I know its incorrect due to the unpacking error.  Any help would be appreciated as I may experience this issue with later scripts as well.

```
def normalizeDataByField(self, fileName,keyNames):

        #this normalizes time how I want
        setTimes = set()
        listTimes = []
        tupleTime=[]
        for i in range(len(fileName)):
            node = self.deriveNodeName(fileName[i])
            nodeTime= '%s-Time' %(node)
            for key in dataDict:
                if 'Time' in key and node in key:
                    for i in dataDict[key]:
                        setTimes.add(i)
            listTimes+=setTimes
            listTimes.sort()
            normalDict['Time'] = listTimes


        for a in range(len(fileName)):
            node = node = self.deriveNodeName(fileName[a])
            nodeTime='%s-Time' %(node)
            for key in keyNames:
                nodeKey= '%s-%s' %(node,key)

                for i,j in normalDict['Time'],dataDict[nodeKey]: #this is my flaw in logic as I get ValueError: too many values to unpack

                    print "looking for %s in dataDict[nodeTime]" %(i)
                    if i in dataDict[nodeTime]:
                        print "%s found in dataDict[%s]" %(i,nodeTime)
                        normalDict[nodeKey].append(j)
                    else:
                        print "%s not found in dataDict[%s]. Appending 'nan'" %(i,nodeTime)
                        normalDict[nodeKey].append('nan')
```

Comment: This question is phrased quite unclear. Are you looking for something like `normalDict[t] = {k: dataDict.get("%s-%s" % (t, k), None) for k in keys]}`?

Comment: I edited my post and added clarification of my goal.  I need to find a way to add create a normalDict[nodeKey] entry with the same number of values as normalDict['Time'], but I need to make sure I add nan's in the correct spots to match nodeTime they correspond with.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe I was able to answer my own question, but its a bit messy.  I decided that I would store each `dataDict[nodeKey]` into a list `dataList` and append values to `normalDict[nodeKey]` based on their list index `j`.  I also found an error in my for loop creating `normalDict['Time']`.

```
def normalizeDataByField(self, fileName,keyNames):
    setTimes = set()
    listTimes = []
    tupleTime=[]
    for i in range(len(fileName)):
        node = self.deriveNodeName(fileName[i])
        nodeTime= '%s-Time' %(node)

        for key in dataDict:
            if nodeTime in key:
                for i in dataDict[key]:
                    setTimes.add(i)
    listTimes+=setTimes
    listTimes.sort()
    normalDict['Time'] = listTimes


    for a in range(len(fileName)):
        node = node = self.deriveNodeName(fileName[a])
        nodeTime='%s-Time' %(node)
        for key in keyNames:
            if 'Time' not in key:
                nodeKey= '%s-%s' %(node,key)
                dataList = dataDict[nodeKey] 
                j=0
                for i in normalDict['Time']:
                    print "looking for %s in dataDict[nodeTime]" %(i)
                    if i in dataDict[nodeTime]:
                        print "%s found in dataDict[%s].  Appending value." %(i,nodeTime)
                        try:
                            normalDict[nodeKey].append(dataList[j])
                            j+=1
                            print "j = ",j
                        except:
                            print "Index out of range. j = ", j
                    else:
                        print "%s not found in dataDict[%s]. Appending 'nan'" %(i,nodeTime)
                        normalDict[nodeKey].append('nan')
    for key in normalDict:
        print "len(normalDict[%s] = %d" %(key, len(normalDict[key]))
```

This last for loop shows that all keys in normalDict have equal lengths.
Maybe this isn't the prettiest solution, but I was able to create a dictionary with the values I needed and putting 'nan' values where necessary to correspond with `normalDict['Time']`

Answer (score 0):

```
time_key='1-Time'
lattitude_key='1-lattitude'

def normalize(normalDict, dataDict, lattitude_key, time_key):
    normalDict[lattitude_key]=['nan' for _ in range(len(normalDict['Time']))]
    for i, e in enumerate(dataDict[time_key]):
        normalDict[lattitude_key][normalDict['Time'].index(e)]=dataDict[lattitude_key][i]
```